# Getting data from Ajax POST request in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, json, post

I'm trying to send a POST request with Ajax, but I'm having trouble getting the values sent in PHP. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "updatedata.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status, xhr)
    {
       //...
    }
});
```

And I want to access the data with PHP. Something like this?

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

My data:

```
{"UID":"00a3b1b0-03b4-11e1-be50-0800200c9a66","Firstname":"Bastian","Lastname":"Sander","UserPenaltys":{"Penalty1":"110","Penalty10":"200","Penalty11":"210","Penalty12":"220","Penalty13":"230","Penalty14":"240","Penalty15":"250","Penalty16":"260","Penalty2":"120","Penalty3":"130","Penalty4":"140","Penalty5":"150","Penalty6":"160","Penalty7":"170","Penalty8":"180","Penalty9":"190"},"PenaltyCounter":16}
```

I tried this:

```
$.post("updatedata.php", JSON.stringify(UserData), function (data) {
}, "json");
```

But `$_POST['Firstname']` is empty...

Comment: You want to parse JSON with PHP, so just check Google and you find this: http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/

Comment: Make a `print_r($_POST)` and have a look how the data looks like. I assume you have to send it a bit differently. The jQuery documentation should provide enough information.

Comment: PHP does not run client side, you are misunderstanding the web stack

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `$.post()`?  The format is:

```
$.post(<URI string>, <postdata object>, <handler>, <datatype>);
```

And then treat the data like any other form post to PHP (i.e. use the `$_POST` variable).

Answer (score 2):

Number one: you do not need to use `JSON.stringify`

Number two: Access them like so:

`$uid = $_POST['UID']; //...etc`

Comment: @user1023663 remove the stringify then all of your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

`$data = $_POST['data'];` - that's wrong.

`$_POST['UID']`, `$_POST['Firstname']`, `$_POST['Lastname']` etc. only be avalable

It can be you even hadn't make some operation like that: JSON.stringify(jsonData); May be will work something like this: `$.ajax({..., data: jsonData, ...});`

You should try to start some traffic analyzer, for example press F12 in google chrome (tab Network), or select opera dragonfly in opera, or another trafic analyzer and resolve some question:
1. is request send to right script and response not an 404 error
2. is received data has right format? (in google chrome on Network tab, click on request for more info)

i think problem will be resolved by this two steps =)